# Express a general vector $(x, y, z)$ in $R^3$ as a linear combination of $(1, 2, 1),(1, 0, -1),(1, -2, 1)$

Tags: linear-algebra

$a + b + c = x$

$2a + 0 - 2c = y$

$a – b + c = z$

Then, $(a + b + c, 2a - 2c, a - b + c) = (x, y, z)$, but this looks horrendous unless they mean I should simplify this somehow or something entirely different. Am I not understanding the question correctly?

Comment: Invert the matrix whose columns are the given vectors.

Comment: @ Francis Begbie, thanks. One caveat: we haven't covered matrixes yet.

Comment: Hint: line 1+line 2 + line 3 gives $4a=x+y+z$ go from there

Comment: @ Tsemo  Aristide, shoulld I get something like this $(\frac{x + y + z}{4}, \frac {x – z)}{2}, \frac {x - y + z}{4}) = (x, y, z)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**: $a+c=\dfrac{x+z}{2}, a-c = \dfrac{y}{2}\Rightarrow 2a = \dfrac{x+y+z}{2}\Rightarrow a = \dfrac{x+y+z}{4}$, and similarly $b = \dfrac{x-z}{2}$. Can you solve for $c$ ?

Comment: @ Kf-Sansoo, $c = \frac {(x + z – y)}{4}$?

Comment: $c = x - (a+b)= x- \dfrac{x+y+z}{4} - \dfrac{x-z}{2}=...$

Comment: I got the same result, sorry :)